# How to search fields in two related channels, but only show results from one?

Tags: relationships, low-search

I have two channels: **blog** and **recipes**. Blog posts are about recipes, so one of the fields in the blog channel is a relationship field connected to the recipes channel. Each blog entry has a related recipe entry.

I want to let visitors search for terms in the **body** field of the blog channel as well as in the **ingredients** field of the recipes channel, but only show the related entry (the recipe) in the search results.

So let's say there's a blog post about pizza, connected to a related recipe for pizza. Within the **body** field of the blog entry, the author has typed "my kids love this." Within the **ingredients** field of the recipe entry, the author has typed  "mozzarella".

I want the pizza recipe entry to show in the results if the user searches for "mozzarella" and also if the user searches for "my kids love this".

Is this possible?

[EDIT]

It seems like the logic I need is something like, "if a result is found in the Recipes channel, then display that entry. If the result is found in the *Blog* channel, then display that entry's related Recipes channel entry."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering entries by a child entry's keywords will require a custom filter, so isn't possible out of the box.

> if a result is found in the Recipes channel, then display that entry. If the result is found in the Blog channel, then display that entry's related Recipes channel entry.

This is possible out of the box. If you create 2 collections -- one for Recipes, one for Blog -- you can search both collections and in the Results tag use conditionals to display different types of content depending on the channel.

The gotcha here is that the excerpt will belong to the collection/channel the entry was found in. And if you're displaying the related Recipe entry for a found Blog entry, it is possible that that specific Recipe entry was already displayed. So there's a chance of duplicate results. One way around that is to also display some Blog entry information there, so it looks different.

Comment: That's exactly what I did and those are indeed the results I'm getting: duplicate results. 

Okay, thanks a lot for the help, Low. I'll figure something out.

Comment: @MikeMella we have a similar challenge, but in reverse... we ONLY want to search entries that are parents of a specific entry. Did you resolve this?

Comment: @paulcripps Not really. My client agreed to only search and show results from one channel.